# Prove that $A^2=A\iff \Sigma K=I_r$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, generalized-inverse

Let $A$ be a square complex matrix and let $A=U\Sigma V^*$ be a singular value decomposition. Then $A$ can be written as

$$A=U\begin{bmatrix}
      \Sigma K & \Sigma L\\
       0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
U^*$$
where  $V^* =\begin{bmatrix}
            K & L\\ M & N
\end{bmatrix}U^*$.
Note that $KK^*+LL^*=I$.

### Question:

> Prove that $$A^2=A \iff \Sigma K=I_r$$

$(\Leftarrow)$ is easy by just verification.

While doing the $(\Rightarrow)$ implication, 
by comparing $A^2$ and $A$ I got

$\left(\Sigma K\right)^2=\Sigma K$ and $\Sigma K \Sigma L=\Sigma L$.

How to proceed further?

Comment: Thank you..I have corrected. @M.Vinay

Comment: If $A$ is a square matrix, aren't $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$ of the same order as $A$? What are the dimensions of $K$ and $L$ then?

Comment: You write 'the' singular value decomposition. I was of the impression that singular value decompositions were not unique. Am I mistaken, or are you using a particular singular value decomposition?

Comment: Thank you...for the observation..you are right..I have made change.@user161825

Comment: Your notation suggests to me that $\Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix whose entries consist of only the strictly positive singular values of $A$, is this correct?

Comment: yes..@user161825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What remains to verify is that $\Sigma K x=x$ for all $x$. Pick $x$. Since $\Sigma$ is positive definite, we may write
\begin{align*}
x&=\Sigma\Sigma^{-1}x=\Sigma(KK^* + LL^*)\Sigma^{-1}x\\
&=\Sigma K(K^*\Sigma^{-1}x)+\Sigma L(L^*\Sigma^{-1}x).
\end{align*}
Since you have already verified that $(\Sigma K)^2=\Sigma K$ and $\Sigma K\Sigma L=\Sigma L$, we find
\begin{align*}
\Sigma K x&=(\Sigma K)^2(K^*\Sigma^{-1}x)+\Sigma K \Sigma L(L^*\Sigma^{-1}x)\\
&=\Sigma K(K^*\Sigma^{-1}x)+\Sigma L(L^*\Sigma^{-1}x)\\
&= x,
\end{align*}
which was what we wanted.